# MySQL login PHP with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I have a script of php via that we can login but I want include in this some condition. In my database column is `status` , `LogCount` , `isMobileConfirmed` at login page I want add like this :

If username or password is matched then..

If `status=0` you are blocked , else= redirect.

If `isMobileConfirmed=0` your mobile not Verified , else=redirect.

If`LogCount=0` your are new user , else=redirect.

Due to limitations in stackoverflow I cant post my code pleas have a [look at my pastebin](https://pastebin.com/G2ffjyeA) and please help to. Create this script as we wish..

Please, thanks in advance..

Comment: You can put the code directly in your question. There is no reputation limitation for including code in your question.

Comment: I was don't know.please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code might help you!

```
if($num>0)
{
    if($ret[0]['status'] == "0") {
        echo "<div class='alert-box warning error'><span>you are blocked</span></div>";
        die();
    }
    else if($ret[0]['isMobileConfirmed'] == "0") {
        echo "<div class='alert-box warning error'><span>your mobile not Verified</span></div>";
        die();
    }
    else if($ret[0]['IfLogCount'] == "0") {
        echo "<div class='alert-box warning error'><span>your are new user</span></div>";
        die();
    }
    else {
        $extra="captcha_auth=user.php";//
        $_SESSION['login']=$_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id']=$num['id'];
        $host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri=rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\');
        header("location:https://$host$uri/$extra");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir why tour code is not working on my code pls have a look here https://pastebin.com/0qfaFXA1

Comment: I already highlighted the php script in pastebin. My issue is your conditions is not working and when username or password is match it's login..

Comment: Please Reply , complete your answe

Comment: I am away from my laptop. Will solve after some hours, learn to write in a good manner.

Comment: I will awaiting for this..Thank you .

Comment: Just noted you had done it all wrong. Go to https://pastebin.com/EDJA4U4F to see the correct version. You may add your own custom logic and next time pay attention to details when you are coding.

Comment: Thank you ! @Ajmal  could you please share your email? I am awaiting for this. don't worry I will not send spam..

Comment: @Atif i think you have to code it yourself and only let me know of the problem. Don’t expect me code it for you.

Comment: Ok I am understand. Could you update your script that after 3 invalid attempt show google rechapta..